# Get 2 doubles from string using only 2 variables challenge

Tags: java

I've been set a challenge on scope and this is really bugging me.

I am passing some data from another class. This string I pass is:

> "41 b 2"

Now I have 1 instance Double variables called x and a local string called x.

I must later on in the code convert the local variable string x and pass the double value of that to another method.

My aim is to take this and place 41 in x (instance variable) and 2 when passing it to method2 as a double also. The n is a splitter. Any number can be either side. I have tried doing x

i'm sure the code must be really simple here. But, i'm not sure what to put in. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I thought about doing String[] x = x.split but that gives me an error of duplication variable. The challenge is I can't create any new variables.

```
 Double x;
  public Double x(String x){
        if (x.contains(" b ")){
 <code need help on> }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the input string x using the separator " b ". `this.x` can be used to point instance variable x. [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) will convert string to double. The following code may help you.

```
if (x.contains(" b ")){
            String[] split = x.split(" b ");
            this.x = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
            method2(split[1]);
        }
```